# How does data-propagation takes place for Same Table present in different schemas

Tags: sql-server

If I create same table say, `Customer` in different schemas of same database, do these tables share common data-storage? In other words. Will changes made into Customer table of one schema be propagated to other schema as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two tables share no relationship whatsoever (aside from a common name). They needn't have the same columns, and changes to one most certainly don't affect the other. At least by default; there may be a trigger or some such that attempts to do this in your particular environment.